# Automapping entities when using FriendsOfSymfony / FOSElasticaBundle implementing Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony-2.3, elastica

Using  FriendsOfSymfony / FOSElasticaBundle with Symfony 2, I need to know if there is anyway i can automap all of the entities with indexing. Or manual entries  is only way i can map entities for implementing Elastica Searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've worked it out by now, but if not have a look in the docs  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle#populate-the-types - Populate the types section
If you set a provider you can then use 
  php app/console fos:elastica:populate